# How to change the background Color of selected item in a list using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here I need to change the background color of an selected item from a list and get the value of the selected Item as well , Please Can anyone help me in this.. Thanks in Advance

Here is my Component

```
const Time = () => {
  const dataTime = useMemo(() => TimeData, []);
  const chunks = useMemo(() => {
    const _chunks = [];
    const tmp = [...dataTime];
    while (tmp.length) {
      _chunks.push(tmp.splice(0, 3));
    }
    //console.log(_chunks);
    return _chunks;
  }, [dataTime]);

  return (
    <div className="Main-Section">
      <div className="First-Section">Time</div>
      <div className="Second-Section">
        <div className="date_title">Wednesday , June 13</div>
        <div className="time_Slots">
          {chunks.map((timeslot) => {
            return (
              <div key={timeslot} className="inline">
                {timeslot.map((time) => {
                  return <p className='timeslots' key={time}>{time}</p>;
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className='new_Date'>PICK A NEW DATE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I beleive there may be better solutions as well, but you could add something like this to your paragraph:

```
{timeslot.map((time) => {
  return <p
    className='timeslots'
    key={time}
    onClick={(event) => yourHandlerFunction(event, time)}
  >
    {time}
  </p>;
})}
```

and then in your handler function you could add a custom class to your element e.g. `selected` or just simply change its background directly

```js
const yourHandlerFunction = (event, time) => {
  event.target.classList.add('selected');
  // ...
};
```

**Edit:** Another approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-list-item-example-zu3qb7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ..Your Solution works but I need to Deselect the previous item, when I Select another item from list... Here all items getting selected when I clicked on any item in list,Here is my code can you make any changes in it?
 const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState();
  const handleSelect = (event,selectedItem) => {
    setSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    event.target.classList.add('selected');
};
<p className='timeslots target' key={time} 
    onClick={(event) => handleSelect(event,time)}>{time}</p>;
p.selected {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}

Comment: Another approach that came into my mind is this: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-list-item-example-zu3qb7?file=/src/App.js and it also handles the deselection. Hope it helps a bit more.